# MVC: String to Long Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I have an input field called "LongArray" in which I want to put a list of numbers (e.g. "100, 101, 102").

How do I store those numbers in the input field so that with posting this form the model binder automatically converts the "LongArray" value to `long[] LongArray` of the expected model in the Post-Controller-Action?

Comment: do you mean `long[] longList = stringlist.Split(',').Select(x => long.Parse(x.Trim())).ToArray();`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add inputs dynamically with javascript with the name of "LongArray" for each one.

Then if your action resembles this, the model binder will pick it up.

```
public ActionResult Post(long[] LongArray)
{
   ...
}
```

Here is a simple example:

**Html**

```
<div id="aDiv"></div>
<input id="numberInput" type="text" >
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#add').click(function () {         
    var anInput = '<input type="hidden" name="LongArray" value=' + $('#numberInput').val() + '></input>';        
    $(anInput).appendTo('#aDiv');
    $('#numberInput').val('');
});
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agmst4eu/1/)**

The above simple appends a hidden input with the required name for the model binder to work.

The single entry is added via a text box that is cleared upon entry.

This renders the following in html which is hidden in the browser:

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: But there is no way to do this with the value of just one input field?

Comment: @Palmi You can have one, input field for adding the value which you clear and have the inputs as hidden. Will add a simple example. 2 mins.

Comment: Thank you. But for sure there is no more elegant solution with one Input field? For example <input type=hidden" name="LongArray" value="100,101,102">. Is there a way to look up what the model binder does with this input?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way will be to use FormCollection and parse String to Array manually.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionMethod(FormCollection form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        const string name = "LongArray";

        IList<long> longArray = form[name] != null
            ? form[name].Split(new[] { ',' }, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => Convert.ToInt64(x)).ToList()
            : new List<long>();


        // Some other fields
        string someInputValue = form["SomeInput"];
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom model binder for this:

```
public class LongBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[bindingContext.ModelName] != null)
        {
            var decodedString = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[bindingContext.ModelName]);
            return decodedString.Split(',').Select(s => long.Parse(s.Trim())).ToArray();
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Now if you have a view like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input name="longArray" value="123, 345, 678" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

And you have action method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestLong([ModelBinder(typeof(LongBinder))]long[] longArray)
{
    // now your longArray contains your desired value.

}
```